# How to draw and label lines and angles

Tags: mathjax

I can draw graphs of simple functions (straight lines and parabolas) one at a time. But how do you render multiple lines at the same time (and label them neatly)? Is there a code for drawing slant lines?

The end state I am going for is something like the one below.

[image]

Would the LaTeX code to achieve this be equivalent to the MathJax code for HTML?

Thank you.

Comment: This is commonly done with a graphic package like `pstricks` or `TikZ`

Comment: Tilting seems to be rotating, and of course you can rotate pictures. `\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=10,nodes={text depth=0.2ex,text height=1.2ex}]
 \draw (-1,1) -- (2,1) node[right]{$k$} 
  (-1,2) -- (2,2) node[right]{$\ell$} 
  (0,3) -- (0,0) node[below]{$t$}
  (0,1) node[below right]{$z^0$}
  (0,2) node[below right]{$y^0$}
  node[above right]{$x^0$}
  node[above left]{$w^0$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`.

Comment: You will not be able to use `TikZ` or `pstricks` in MathJax, however.

Comment: @Davide Cervone Yes, I noticed that the code for TikZ doesn't work in MathJax environment. What is a package similar to TikZ that can be used in MathJax?

Comment: @SamChoi, MathJax does not have a graphics package, currently.  It might be possible to do something with CSS tricks to make this particular diagram, but it would be a hack.